# Proper usage of javax.annotation.Nonnull

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

I would like to know whether I should put `javax.annotation.Nonnull` annotation before each parameter:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
interface Foo {
    void bar(@Nonnull Integer x, @Nonnull String y);
}
```

or put it only before method signature:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
@Nonnull
interface Foo {
    void bar(Integer x, String y);
}
```

I'm using Intellij Code Inspection.

Comment: I would put it in front of each parameter: what if you add a parameter to the method signature and it can be null?

Comment: @Nathan I agree with you, but I had a debate with my colleague, so I want to make thing clear and explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Before each parameter is a more concrete definition.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that both approaches are applicable?

Comment: Both approaches achieve the same goal of alerting if a null could pass through.